# Options for eliminating cross server joins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database on server X containing my source data.
I also have a database on server Y that contains data I need to augment with data on server X.

Currently we have a nightly job on server Y that calls a stored procedure on server X, inserts it into a table variable, then sends the data as xml to a stored procedure in the database on server Y.

Below is a basically what the code looks like:

```
--Get data from source
DECLARE @MySourceData TABLE 
(
    [ColumnX] VARCHAR(50),    
    [ColumnY] VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO @MySourceData EXECUTE [ServerX].SourceDatabase.dbo.[pListData];

DECLARE @XmlData XML;
SELECT 
    @XmlData =
    (
        SELECT 
            [ColumnX]  
            ,[ColumnY]
        FROM
            @MySourceData 
        FOR XML RAW ('Item'), ROOT('Items'), ELEMENTS, TYPE
    )

--Send data to target
EXEC TargetDatabase.dbo.pImportData @XmlData;
```

This approach keeps any server names or database names within the sql of the job step (which we think of as part of configuration), and allows us to abide by our in house development standards of using stored procedures for data access.  While this particular solution is only processing a few thousand records, and the xml won't get that big, if we tried applying it in scenarios where the dataset was larger, how poorly it might scale.  I'm curious if others have better suggestions.

Comment: I think using SSIS package would definitely be a better option for you. You will set up your connections without the need to have linked server problem. You can easily set up a job to execute this package on nightly basis.

Comment: Have you looked at using replication to bring the tables that you need from the remote server to your local?